# Scp doesn't finish, even after a reboot

Tags: scp

For some reason, I'm trying to transfer a simple 0KB file from one system to the next using SCP and it's just hanging at 100%. I've enabled the `-vvv` flags but still have no idea what this verbose output even means. Here's what it looks like after it hits 100%:

```
debug2: channel 0: written 23 to efd 6
test.txt                                                                                                                                                                          100%    0     0.0KB/s   00:00
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
```

I've tried to restart the remote SSH server as well, but that didn't work. It's just running a fresh installation of Kali Linux with no modifications.

Any idea why this may be happening and how to resolve this problem? It's definitely not the client becuse I just uploaded the same file to another system via SCP, but I'm not sure what's going on with the server that would cause this.

Comment: Could you give more information on the scp client and server? By the way, it could still be the client mishandling a different server response.

Comment: Sure. The client is running Kali Linux 2020.1 and the server is just a fresh Ubuntu 19.10 server.

Comment: Ok, I meant something more along the lines of ssh -V. No idea of what Kali or Ubuntu are shipping.

Comment: Also, the debug output is missing some important parts. I just tried the sending of an empty file and having seen my log I think that you might want include all the lines after "sending command" (debug1) / send packet type 98 (debug3), to be able to reconstruct the exchange and understand what happens.

Comment: On the remote system--the system which scp connects to--do you have anything unusual in your .bashrc or other shell startup files? For example do you launch any processes which run in the background?

Comment: Thanks guys. @Kenster actually you are correct. I had a command in my .bashrc file that would test to see if a process was running, and run it if it wasn't. I didn't realize that SCP had anything to do with the .bashrc file. That fixed my problem! Thanks for your help too Eduardo!